# Three.js replacing "Teapot geometry model" with "JSON Model"

Tags: javascript, json, 3d, three.js

Been through the introduction tuturial. got the green cube working.
Replaced it with a json model. **very exciting!**

Then i tried to do the same with the teapot one. or the car.
Because i want a bit more detail and a texture on my model.
But for some reason nothing keeps showing up when i want to replace them.
With my own JSON model (exported from blender).

Also its hard to find any example that uses JSON.
Even the blender example does not use JSON for some reason.

I am trying to achieve a nice turntable effect for showcasing my models.
Would be even way more amazing if it had keyframe dragging below aswell for animating.

Links to examples:
http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_teapot
http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_ctm_materials

Thank you for reading!

Comment: you try http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Loaders/JSONLoader

Comment: yeah i finally managed to get something working. But now the textures wont load though :P. dont you think its strange that the blender json example has dae loader stuff insteads of json loader?